# Query string as parameter in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to pass a query string as parameter in my `htaccess`, this is the example:

I receive as parameter something like that:

```
#frm=q%3D%26Page%3D1%26LotTypes%3DV%26RadioGroup%3DLocation%26PostalCode%3D%26
```

and the url looks like:

```
www.mydomain.com/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3/#frm=q%3D%26Page%3D1%26LotTypes%3DV%26RadioGroup%3DLocation%26PostalCode%3D%26
```

and I have my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^busquedas/(\w+)/(.+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ detallesCtlr.php?make=$1&model=$2&yearFrom=$3&yearTo=$4&page=$5&filter=$6 [L,QSA]
```

So the idea is to pass through the last parameter "$filter" a query string as parameter. Ideas?

Comment: The `#` (hashes) are not understood by Apache/server. It is a client side feature